# Why is my For Loop, If statement, and append method not working the way I was expecting

Tags: python

I am trying to organise certain words in a particular order using the below function. The aim is for the function to pick up the number values and create a list (sporting) in numerical order. Calling the function with this argument "is2 Thi1s T4est 3a" should return a list in the following order ["Thi1s", "is2", "3a", "T4est"]
However I am getting an empty list.

```py
def order(sentence):
    
    y = list(sentence.split())
    
    sporting = []
    counter = 1
    for i in y:
        if str(counter) in i:
            sporting.append(i)
            
        counter += 1
        
    print(counter)
        
        
       
    print(y)  
    print(sporting)

order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a")
```

The result of printing sporting should be a list in the order of Thi1s is2 3a T4est
however the only value I get is [] when printing sporting.

Please could someone explain to my what I am doing wrong. I'm a newbie to Python.
Thank you.

The counter continues to run until 5, however nothing is populated in the sporting list. I have tried change the placement of the counter += 1 and that has not given me the results I want.

Comment: a good start will be to examine both `i` and `counter` just before your `if` (you can just add another`print`)

Comment: Add `print(i, counter)` as first statement in your for loop's body and run your program again. Then you will see, why nothing is added to your result array

Comment: But even if you got your counter right for your condition to work, you won't get a sorted result, because it's just impossible to sort an array with a single traversal ...

Comment: Your goal is to check every possible number to see if its in the word. But there is an infinite number of them. And as soon as you get over 9, you get false positives like `"1" in "10"`. Is `count` limited to a single digit?

Comment: Find a tutorial that shows how to use a debugger. Doing so, you can step through the code and inspect its state, which will allow you to quickly find where it takes the wrong turn and also why. Also, it helps to extract a [mcve], which is also required for questions here. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

`i in y` is never true

```
"1" in "is2"
"2" in "Thi1s"
```

Changing how the counter iterates won't work since the numbers in the sentence are not increasing in the same order

> should be a list in ... order

Then `in` isn't what you want to test. You should parse the number out of each string for example using regex, then use `sorted` function

For example, build a list of tuples

```
[(2, is2), (1,Thi1s)]
```

Then sort on the first element (sorted function takes a `key` parameter), then extract your second elements to get the order you want

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can filter for digits in sentence then zip it with splitted sentence and lastly get second element of sorted tuple:

```
def order(sentence):
    # import re
    # digits = re.findall('(\d+)', sentence)
    digits = [*filter(str.isdigit, sentence)]
    sporting = [i[1] for i in sorted(zip(digits,sentence.split()))]
    print(sporting)

order("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a")
order("is3 Thi4s T2est 1a")
order("is1 Thi2s T4est 3a")
order("is3 Thi2s T1est 4a")

# ['Thi1s', 'is2', '3a', 'T4est']
# ['1a', 'T2est', 'is3', 'Thi4s']
# ['is1', 'Thi2s', '3a', 'T4est']
# ['T1est', 'Thi2s', 'is3', '4a']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. No need to use the counter. Directly get the value using isdigit() function

```
for word in y:
    for char in word:
        if char.isdigit():
            index = int(char) - 1 # converting char value to index
            sporting.append(y[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need arbitrarily many numbers, your approach simply won't do, because `1` in `h10ello` will fire off early on.

You need to extract the numeric part from every word, and then sort the list based on that number.

To get the numeric part, the most obvious approach is to use a regex:

```py
def extract_number_from_word(word):
    import re
       
    # findall gives us a list of all matches
    # we take the first (and only)
    # then we convert it to integer
    return int(re.findall('(\d+)', word)[0])
```

Then you can simply sort the list based on the number:

```py
words.sort(key=extract_number_from_word)
```

Overall, you get the following:

```py
def order(sentence):
    def extract_number_from_word(word):
        import re
        
        return int(re.findall('(\d+)', word)[0])
        
    words = list(sentence.split())
    
    words.sort(key=extract_number_from_word)
                
    print(words)

order(" is2 Thi1s T4est 3a h10ello wor9ld")
# ['Thi1s', 'is2', '3a', 'T4est', 'wor9ld', 'h10ello']
```